# Влияет ли js фреймворк на скорость загрузки сайта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Есть сайт, на котором размещается много качественных изображений, скорость загрузки соответственно плохая. Если сделать этот сайт с помощью js фреймворка например vue js или react js, улучшится скорость загрузки сайта или нет?

Comment: Если исходить из того, что у вас загружаются изображения в хорошем качестве и весят много, то вам вряд ли поможет фреймворк, так как на скорость загрузки файлов он повлиять не может. А так вопрос довольно филосовский, так как надо детально изучать ваш сайт и смотреть, что с ним можно сделать.

Comment: Откройте панель разработчика в Хроме, Network. Справа будет "водопадик" загрузки. По нему и смотрите, на что тратится время. Если кратко - JS скорее всего тут не при чем, но возможно ситуация немного улучшится, если со скриптами совсем все ужасно.

Comment: PS. Используйте [прогрессивное сжатие в JPEG](https://habrahabr.ru/post/165645/) чтобы "визуально" не заставлять скучать посетителя.

Answer (score 1):

Не факт. Нужно видеть сам сайт что бы развернуто ответить. Для начала нужно делать отложенную загрузку самих изображений и делать превью в более низком разрешении. И скажем при прокрутки уже вставлять следующие изображения, если позволяет дизайн. Если вставка делается в огромном количестве то да. какой то из этих фреймворком ускорит рендер 100% из-за минимума манипуляций с DOM.
Они лишь помогут ускорить insert в DOM, но саму загрузку изображений они не увеличат. Тут нужно подходить со всех сторон к вопросу.